# Ambari:Error while enabling kerberos

Tags: kerberos, hadoop2, ambari

I have installed Ambari 2.5.0 version with HDP 2.6 and added some of the services but while enabling kerberos I am facing one weird issue.

```
resource_management.core.exceptions.Fail: Execution of 'curl -sS -L -w '%
{http_code}' -X GET --negotiate -u : 'http://xxxx:50070/webhdfs/v1/ats/done?
op=GETFILESTATUS&user.name=hdfs'' returned status_code=403. 
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
  <title>Error 403   
   org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticationException
 </title

</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 403</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /webhdfs/v1/ats/done. Reason:
<pre>    
org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticationException
</pre>
  </p><hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><br/>                                                
 <br/>
```

My installation is getting failed while installing the APP time line server.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: `&user.name=hdfs` does not make any sense when using Kerberos authentication. Hadoop takes the _principal_ from your Kerberos ticket, applies the "user mapping rules" to translate it to a Hadoop user (e.g. `X12_alpha@WTF.ORG` mapped to `x12`) and uses it instead of `user.name`. Cf. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html#Authentication

Comment: I am enabling kerebros from ambari only and for other cluster i have not got any such issues but for this one i am getting this ,i am not able to find   where i am doing the mistake.

Comment: You mean it's Ambari that generates that silly `curl` command? Do you have any idea of which Kerberos principal is present in the ticket cache, and used by `curl` for SPNEGO auth (cf. `--negotiate`)? And did you check that the access privileges on that file (or directory) `hdfs:///ats/done` are similar in both clusters?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter i pretty much sure that user.name arg ignored by hadoop on Kerberos auth on. The problem i see is error code 403, what means that requested resource not present or user have no access to requested resource.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I was asking about the actual permissions on that resource + the actual authenticated user. My guess is that some Ambari action has failed and the error was not properly trapped...